# Expo publish also update ejected expo app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

Does expo publish automatically update the app? or uploading to app store is necessary after every updates.

I want to update my IOS app. I have ejected my project so every time I need to update my app I expo publish and upload my app through xcode. I was wondering if expo publish automatically updates the app.

Answer (score 0):

`expo publish` will upload package bundle to Expo server (or your private server). The app will notice that there is an update, and download it. But if you ejected your app, you need to compile your `.IPA` file by yourself and submit to App Store.

Comment: I have ejected app published in app store. I downloaded my app from app store in a device. And when I 'expo publish' ,the new update was automatically shown in my device. I am so confused. I wonder that if the local network is doing the updates or is it supposed to work like that?